# In GHC are non-tail functions transformed to CPS?

Tags: haskell

This code is used in Learn You A Haskell to explain how (++) can be inefficient if it is used to build out a list to the right instead of to the left:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer  

gcdReverse :: Int -> Int -> Writer [String] Int  
gcdReverse a b  
    | b == 0 = do  
        tell ["Finished with " ++ show a]  
        return a  
    | otherwise = do  
        result <- gcdReverse b (a `mod` b)  
        tell [show a ++ " mod " ++ show b ++ " = " ++ show (a `mod` b)]  
        return result
```

Since we are not doing tail recursion here is it correct to assume that GHC will transform this function into a CPS style function during compilation?  If this transform is in fact happening can I expect it from all Haskell compilers, or is it just a GHC thing.

I understand this function is inefficient because it is appending the list the wrong way, but I just want to make sure there won't cause a stack overflow.

Comment: I think that you have some misunderstanding about CPS.  Converting a code to CPS does not reduce the amount of required memory.  If the original code would cause stack overflow, then the CPS version still causes stack or heap overflow.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, er... I thought that CPS converting gave you tail call optimization for free.  I could be mistaken.

Comment: Googled, found this interesting tidbit: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/CPS

Comment: @luqui: You are right, and my first comment was not accurate enough.  I should have said: converting a _non-tail-call_ code to CPS does not reduce the amount of required memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, GHC does not do CPS conversion. Although there are variants of the CPS conversion for lazy languages, I know of no compiler for a lazy language which actually performs CPS conversion.

You're right in that CPS conversion can trade stack space for heap space, but some compilers which employs the CPS conversion treats the continuations specially so that they effectively get a heap allocated stack, and so you will get a stack overflow anyway. I think this is a good thing because it helps debugging. And, as for heap allocated stacks, GHC does that too, without CPS conversion. That's how it deals with its lightweight threads implementation.

Comment: Can you clarify what a heap allocated stack means?

Comment: Normally, in conventional programming language implementations, the stack lives in a different address space than the heap. The two are completely separated. But a heap allocated stack means that the stack lives inside the heap and is treated much like any other heap object. This technique is often combined with allocating the stack in chunks, where parts of the stack can be shared between threads or different invocations of continuations. HTH.